# Paradox inequality

Tags: inequality, paradoxes

By doing exercises, I applied a reasoning in a demonstration, that looking at it well, it seems paradoxical.

Let's take a real number $\ a>0 $.

Then $b( \epsilon ) = a+ \epsilon > a $, for each $\ 0< \epsilon <1 $.

$\ b^2( \epsilon ) = (a+ \epsilon )^2 = (a^2 + 2 a \epsilon +\epsilon ^2) < a^2 + 2 a \epsilon + \epsilon $

$\ b^2( \epsilon ) < a^2 + \epsilon (2a+1)$

Since $\ \epsilon $ is as small as I want and it must always be that $\ b^2( \epsilon ) < a^2 + \epsilon (2a+1)$ 
then it means that:

$\ b^2( \epsilon ) \leq a^2 $

so $\ b( \epsilon ) \leq a $, that contradicts $\ b( \epsilon )> a $.

where am I wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using an example?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you make it so complicated? Here is a much simpler way to get a contradiction using your idea. Define
$$f(\epsilon)=\epsilon\text{ for }\epsilon\gt0.$$ So $$f(\epsilon)\gt0.$$ On the other hand, $$f(\epsilon)\le\epsilon.$$ Since I can make $\epsilon$ as small as I want this means that $$f(\epsilon)\le0,$$ which contradicts $f(\epsilon)\gt0.$

> If you can see what I did wrong, maybe you can see that you made the same mistake in your argument.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is intended to illustrate the mistake, but this is false as well for the same reason as the original "contradiction".

Comment: I'm sorry, I just didn't understand why would you make an answer intentionally confusing... you're basically using the same idea without really making the mistake stand out (more than in the original argument, that is). Nevertheless, I apologize for not realizing it was on purpose.

Comment: @GuidoA. We have a difference of opinion. In my opinion, simplifying and shortening the argument, getting rid of the distracting algebra, **does** make the mistake stand out. I was hoping that the OP would see what was wrong with my "argument" and then see that he was making the same mistake.

Comment: That's a fair point.

Comment: Yes, thank you!
So $\ \Biggr( b<a+ \epsilon \; , \forall \epsilon >0 \Biggl)\Rightarrow \Biggr( b \leq a\Biggl) $ is true only when b is a fixed number.
If b is a function of $\ \epsilon $ then $\ b( \epsilon ) $ "moves down" when $\ a+ \epsilon $ "moves down", so at the same time b can also be greater than a.

Right?

Comment: @BiagioIanero You got it.

Comment: @GuidoA. My standard advice for students who are perplexed because they have proved something that can't be true, but can't find a mistake in their reasoning, is to try to simplify the false proof as much as possible. In the present instance, there is no need to derive a paradox for every real number $a,$ one paradox is enough, so the first step would be to specialize to the case $a=0.$

Comment: I agree this strategy is indeed useful, though I feel it may be not as effective over the internet (OP may be not familiar enough with limits to spot the mistake even when simplifying the argument) and that's why I usually take a more forward approach. Anyway, sorry for the useless comment, I probably shouldn't post when lacking sleep.

Answer (score 2):

You're taking the limit of $\epsilon \to 0$ on the left hand side, but on the right side $\epsilon$ is still fixed. What is actually true is that

$$
a^2 = b^2(0) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} b^2(\epsilon) \leq a^2 
$$

Where the second equality is because $b^2$ is continous. Therefore, there is no such contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$\varepsilon$ is as small as you want, but it can never become negative.

Take $a=10$, and your process ends up with $b^2(\varepsilon) < 100 + 21 \varepsilon$.

This does not contradict $b^2(\varepsilon) \ge 100$.